# VS 2017 NetStandard XAML IntelliSense

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, intellisense

Using VS 2017 RTM (and the latest preview from 3/16/2017) I am unable to get Xamarin Forms IntelliSense working in a shared project that targets NetStandard 1.4. It works in a PCL but once I target NetStandard (or create a new project library targeting NetStandard) I get no IntelliSense. Here is the relevant section of the CSPROJ file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
        <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+net45+wp8+win81+wpa8;uap10.0;net46</PackageTargetFallback>
        <AssemblyName>MyApp.AppX</AssemblyName>
        <RootNamespace>MyApp.AppX</RootNamespace>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Do you use Resharper? Disabling Resharper makes my IntelliSense working...

Comment: Updating Resharper to 2017.3.1 version fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

It is a bug from Resharper and they have fixed in their latest beta. You can download the beta version of Resharper from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/eap/)